# Problems creating cloudwatch subscription filter using terraform and localstack

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, localstack

I'm trying to get cloudwatch invoke a lambda function using Terraform and localstack.

I'm trying to use the [aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter.html) but every time I try to run `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error creating Cloudwatch log subscription filter: InvalidParameterException:
  Could not execute the lambda function.
  Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to execute your function.
```

I understand that I need to use the [aws_lambda_permission](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html) resource, but something is failing and I can't figure out what it is. My best guess is that I'm missing some role or permissions. I'm a bit new to most of this so I'm probably just missing something obvious. Here are my configuration files:

**docker-compose.yml** - For running localstack

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:0.11.2
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
      - "${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}:${PORT_WEB_UI-8080}"
    environment:
      - SERVICES=iam,lambda,logs
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG- }
      - DATA_DIR=${DATA_DIR- }
      - PORT_WEB_UI=${PORT_WEB_UI- }
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker-reuse
      - KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY=${KINESIS_ERROR_PROBABILITY- }
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp/localstack}:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

**main.tf**

```
# Localstack provider
provider "aws" {
  profile = "local"
  region = "us-east-1"

  access_key = "fake"
  secret_key = "fake"

  s3_force_path_style = true

  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true

  endpoints {
    lambda = "http://localhost:4566"
    iam = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatch = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatchlogs = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}

# IAM Role for the Lambda Function
resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam_for_lambda"
  description = "Just a test role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

variable "lambda_zip" {
  default="dist/lambda.zip"
}


# This is the lambda function that is generating the cloudwatch logs
resource "aws_lambda_function" "simple_log" {
  function_name = "simple_log"
  filename = var.lambda_zip
  handler = "myapp.lambdas.do_simple_log"
  runtime = "python3.7"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.lambda_zip)
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
}

# This is the lambda I want to trigger when cloudwatch logs trigger
resource "aws_lambda_function" "log_metrics" {
  function_name = "log_metrics"
  filename = var.lambda_zip
  handler = "myapp.lambdas.collect_log_metrics"
  runtime = "python3.7"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.lambda_zip)
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
}

# Pretty sure this is broken, but I don't know why.
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_subscription_filter" "logs_to_initial_lambda" {
  name = "logs_to_initial_lambda"
  log_group_name = "/aws/lambda/simple_log"
  destination_arn = aws_lambda_function.log_metrics.arn
  filter_pattern = ""
}

# These are all the various permissions I've tried with no success.
# They all have the same error.
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch1" {
  statement_id = "my_id_1"
  action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"

  # Tried "000000000000", also didn't work
  principal = "logs.amazonaws.com"

  # Tried aws_lambda_function.log_metrics.function_name
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.log_metrics.arn

  # Tried various source_arns
  # source_arn = "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:000000000000:log-group:*:*"
  # source_arn = "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:000000000000:log-group:*:*"
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you run it against real AWS?

Comment: Yes, a modified version of this is working in real AWS.

Comment: you're principal is missing a region